# Does not match the JNDI name <null> of the message destination

Tags: webserver, websphere

> MapMessageDes W   ADMA0182W: The JNDI name queue/TestDrivenBean specified for the message destination reference queue/TestDrivenBean does not match the JNDI name <null> of the message destination

Does anyone have any idea about this error?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Can you share with us the code that is triggering this error?

Answer (score 0):

Check the configuration of your message destination references (see this [knowledge center article](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/ae/urun_app_msgdestref.html)) to see if there is one called queue/TestDrivenBean that is not bound to any destination.

Comment: How to get rid of this version issue; 
                                                      
**bold                    com.ibm.ws.exception.RuntimeError
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: JVMCFRE003 bad major version;                    bold**

Comment: The UnsupportedClassVersionError probably ought to have been reported as a separate StackOverflow question rather than tacking on to this one.  A quick guess is that you might be compiling against a newer version of Java than you are running with.